# how to fix pandas convert dataframegroupby object to dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have this issue with a groupby operation in pandas, I executed some instructions to get a groupby and convert it to a dataframe, but there is a line/index I cannot remove at the very beggining of the new dataframe

[image]

. I need to remove the line YearsCode in the row axis

I tried to remove the 0 index in the row but it is not working.

[image]

Comment: do reset_index()